# CRM 2013 Entity.GetAttributeValue<T> datetime to string

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-2013

When adding an date record to crm 2013, its removing 2 hours from my record. 
Which is an expected behavoir of the crm as a timezones correction.

The next expected behavior, retreiving the entity using the organisationService RetrieveMultiple api call, returns me the same record without the extra 2 hours.

Now the strange magic begins, when using the Entity.GetAttributeValue(fieldname) it should give me the datetime with the extra 2 hours as it is a setting from the crm. But this is what i get:

```
Create record: '01/10/2014'
CRM stores: '30/09/2014 22:00:00'
Retreive entity results to: '30/09/2014 22:00:00'
Use Entity.GetAttributeValue<DateTime>(fieldname) results to: '30/09/2014 00:00:00'
```

Why does it not say 01/10/2014 after using that method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetAttributeValue` is just an helper, if the DateTime field value inside CRM is `null`, `GetAttributeValue` returns `DateTime.MinValue`.

You need always to use `.ToLocalTime()` to get the local DateTime value instead of the UTC value.

Comment: How many times will people ask UTC related questions?  They're always in a slightly different aspect, so they're not really duplicates but I think you and I have answered like 10 between us.